# Why is package-protected method not visible in the same package?

Tags: java, package

Assume we have two packages `p1` and `p2` and classes `p1.M1` extended by `p2.M12` as follows:

```
package p1;

public class M1 {
    void method1() {
        System.out.println("Method 1 called");
    }
}


package p2;

import p1.M1;

public class M12 extends M1 {
    void method2() {
        System.out.println("Method 2 called");
    }
}
```

Let's extend `M12` with `p2.B`:

```
package p2;

public class B extends M12 {

    public void doSomething()  {
        method1();
        method2();
    }
}
```

This gives a compilation error as `method1`, being package-protected within `p1` is not visible in `p2`. `method2` is visible without problems.

Now let's extend `p2.M12` with `p1.A`:

```
package p1;

import p2.M12;

public class A extends M12 {

    public void doSomething() {
        method1();
        method2();
    }
}
```

Here I'm getting a compilation error for both `method2()` (which is understandable) *and* `method1()`:
[image: The method method1 from the type M1 is not visible]

My question is: why is the `method1` which is package-protected in the package `p1` is not visible in the class `A` from the same package `p1`?

Comment: That would mean that a child class would see more than its parent. That does sound kind of weird.

Comment: @luk2302 That package-protected method is not within in the package is also weird.

Comment: Here is the most relevant part of the JLS I have managed to find: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.4.3

Comment: Suppose you could call `method1` from class `A` and then somebody later added a `public` method called `method1` to the class `M12`. In that situation, which method should be called from within `A`? If the new method gets called, the addition of the new method would have changed the behaviour. If the original `method1` was still called, you would have a public method that it is impossible to call from a particular package.

Comment: You can call `method1`, it's just that you have to cast to the type `M1` -
 `((M1) this).method1()` - which makes sense to me because `method1` is not part of the public API of `M12`.

Comment: @PaulBoddington Sorry, that argument does not hold. You can override methods in subclasses and nobody has problems with "which method should be called" or the changed behaviour.

Comment: @PaulBoddington Since `A` *is* `instanceof M1`, I don't see how casting `this` to `M1` would make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, what is a member of a class? The [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.6) states

> A class body may contain declarations of members of the class, that
> is, fields (§8.3), methods (§8.4), classes (§8.5), and interfaces
> (§8.5).

And what are they composed of? The [JLS states](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.2)

> The members of a class type are all of the following:
>
> - Members **inherited** from its **direct superclass** (§8.1.4), except in class Object, which has no direct superclass
> - Members inherited from any direct superinterfaces (§8.1.5)
> - Members **declared in the body of the class** (§8.1.6)

It also mentions

> Only members of a class that are declared `protected` or `public` are
> inherited by subclasses declared in a package other than the one in
> which the class is declared.

All of this is reworded in the [chapter on Inheritance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8)

> A class `C` inherits from **its direct superclass** all concrete methods `m`
> (both static and instance) of the superclass for which all of the
> following are true:
>
> - `m` is a member of the direct superclass of `C`.
> - `m` is `public`, `protected`, or **declared with package access in the same package as C`**.
> - No method declared in `C` has a signature that is a subsignature (§8.4.2) of the signature of `m`.

The members of class `M1` are `method1` (and all the methods of `Object`). `M12`, being in a different package than its direct superclass, `M1`, does not inherit `method1`. The members of `M12` are therefore only `method2`.

The direct superclass of `B` is `M12` and is in the same package. It therefore inherits its member, `method2`. `B` knows nothing about `method1`. If you had compiled your code with `javac`, you would have received a `cannot find symbol` compilation error instead. (It seems Eclipse is trying to guess what you were trying to do.)

Similarly, the direct superclass of `A` is `M12`, but is in a different package. It does not inherit `method2` for that reason. `A` doesn't know anything about `method1` or `method2` because it didn't inherit them. Both of those symbols cannot be found.

Answer (score 3):

I think the easiest way to understand this behavior is the idea of "A is a M12"

When you declared the inheritance, you told A to get its behavior from M12, but M12 has no visible method called method1.

Let's do an experiment for fun:

```
public class M12 extends p1.M1 {
    public void method1() {
        System.out.println("Method 1 called");
    }
    void method2() {
        System.out.println("Method 2 called");
    }
}
```

Forget A.. when you declare such method, it is allowed - if you do not have an @Override on it.
however, if M1 was:

```
public class M1 {
    public void method1() {
        System.out.println("Method 1 called");
    }
}
```

you could have:

```
public class M12 extends p1.M1 {
    @Override
    public void method1() {
        System.out.println("Method 1 called");
    }

    void method2() {
        System.out.println("Method 2 called");
    }
}
```

now, back to the original code for M1 and M2 with the method re-declared and method one made public:

```
public class M12 extends p1.M1 {
    public void method1() {
        System.out.println("Method 1 called");
    }

    public void method2() {
        System.out.println("Method 2 called");
    }
}
```

Then, you would be able to have

```
public class A extends M12 {

    public void doSomething() {
        method1();
        method2();
    }
}
```

ok, this is a trivial case, but would be missing to complete the sequense...
bottom line, semantically, you could explain by the IS relationship.

---

If more is needed (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html):

The following table shows the access to members permitted by each modifier.

Access Levels

```
Modifier    Class   Package Subclass    World

public      Y       Y       Y           Y

protected   Y       Y       Y           N

no modifier Y       Y       N           N

private     Y       N       N           N
```

Comment: You conveniently ignore that `A` is *also* `M1`. And `M1` does have a method `method1` visible in `p1`. Sure we can make everything public and consider this FTFY but this is not what the question is about. You've quoted a table with access levels - there is is "no modifier - package Y". `A` is in the same package as `M1.method1()` so what's the explanation?

Comment: Also note the overuse annotation behavior that should help.

Comment: I did not ignored. It just seemed to be the same case, and It falls under the other answer, which I upvoted as someone had downvoted it. this is an odd inheritance case- yes A is M1 but it is not where it gets its behavior from, which is kind of a linear process. We can maybe talk of access modifier in a child member here as it is similar in behavior. Suppose your child class expands the level of access for a method. A child of its child would not be able to restore the original level of access, only expand it further.. odd cases like those are on the set that make inheritance bad when deep.

Comment: Semantically, it would be really odd to have a grandchild inheriting something its father could not. As far as programing goes, would be extremely messy if the language allowed such behaviour in a deep structure .

Comment: The language apparently does allow to restrict the child to do something the father could do. `M12` can't use `method1`, `M1` can.

Answer (score 1):

Visibility must flow through the class hierarchy.

The class hierarchy is `A --> M12 --> M1`

The since `M1.method1` is not visible to `M12`, it's not visible to any subclasses of it either, like `A`.

Comment: "Visibility must flow through the class hierarchy." - why?

Comment: "Why" - it's the way the language works - is it worthwhile to dig up the spec that defines this, or just to know "that's the way the language is designed to work"?

Comment: I'd be interested in the pointer to this in the spec if you have it handy.

Comment: "is it worthwhile to dig up the spec that defines this" - I think it is pretty interesting to find this out.

Comment: If someone else posts an answer that includes more details & reference to it, I'll upvote that - I don't have time at the moment to do the detailed research. My hope was that this was useful enough to help OP with their problem & allow them to consider alternative designs to the problem they're trying to solve