# Weird Android Studio error with Java 8

Tags: java, android, java-8, android-studio-3.0

I just upgraded to Android Studio 3.0 from 2.3.3 and was eager to try the new Java 8 features now supported on pre-API 26 builds. I set `sourceCompatibility` and `targetCompatibility` to `JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8` in my build.gradle file. Then, unfortunately, I got an error in the following class:

```
package com.zigzagworld.util;

import java.util.LinkedHashMap;

public class LRUCache<K, V> extends LinkedHashMap<K, V> {
    private final int maxSize;

    public LRUCache(int maxSize) {
        super(Math.min(16, (int) ((maxSize + 1) / 0.75f)), 0.75f, true);
        this.maxSize = maxSize;
    }

    @Override protected boolean removeEldestEntry(Entry<K, V> eldest) {
        return size() > maxSize;
    }
}
```

The error is:

> Error:(13, 51) error: Entry is not public in LinkedHashMap; cannot be accessed from outside package

The editor itself shows no error at all; it only shows up as output from the Gradle task `:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac`.

I'm using the default tool chain. I tried cleaning and rebuilding the project. I also tried invalidating the caches and restarting Android Studio.

I can avoid the error by changing the language back to 1.7 in my build.gradle file. Unfortunately, since my `minSdkVersion` is 17, I then wouldn't be able to use try-with-resources and other goodies.

Interestingly, I discovered that I can work around the error by using the fully qualifying name `java.util.Map.Entry` instead of `Entry`. I have no idea why this works, while the bare name `Entry` generates an error.

Is there some configuration setting I'm missing? Is this a known bug in AS 3.0?

Comment: This shouldn't work on 7 either. `LinkedHashMap.Entry` shadows `Map.Entry`. As such, `Map.Entry` is not inherited by your subclass of `LinkedHashMap`, `LRUCache`. You need to qualify the type to use it. Since `Map` _is_ inherited, you can use `Map.Entry<K, V>`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis - Does a private class in a superclass shadow a class inherited from a parent interface?

Comment: Inheritance won't skip levels. `LRUCache` inherits only from `LinkedHashMap`, where a type named `Entry` is not available. You can have `LRUCache` additionally `implements Map<K,V>` to make `Entry` available again.

Comment: [Something similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46717820/why-is-package-protected-method-not-visible-in-the-same-package/46733634#46733634).

Comment: Perhaps Android's implementation of `LinkedHashMap` didn't have an `Entry` type in earlier releases.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis - I think you're right. The JLS says: _"If a class declares a member type with a certain name, then the declaration of that type is said to hide any and all accessible declarations of member types with the same name in superclasses and superinterfaces of the class."_ Furthermore, even in Java 7, the Javadoc for `AbstractMap` lists `Map.Entry` as an inherited nested class, but doesn't for `HashMap`. So `Map.Entry` is hidden by `HashMap`. Perhaps this is a bug with Android's 1.7 tool chain that was fixed for 1.8. Post your comment as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must take the map from the Entry

```
@Override
 protected boolean removeEldestEntry (Map.Entry<K,V> eldest) {
  return size() > maxSize;
  }
```

this line  `Map.Entry`

We need to get the Entry from the Map interface because the Entry interface was previously made, but it was defined in the latest updates to the Map interface.
Now we have to call the Map to access the interface or Changing the package and folder caused this

Comment: Since Sotirios never posted his comment as a proper answer, you get the credit for posting it. :)